# Pointers in C - "Segmentation Fault" when structuring matrix

Tags: c, matrix, struct, segmentation-fault

I am using Eclipse on a 32-bit Ubuntu virtual machine to work on a project. I have a big problem when trying to implement a structure or just when trying to run a specific function. The function is this one:

```
int count (matrix m, int v[], int w[], int col) {

    int r=0;
    int j=0;

    while (j < m.length) {
        int k=0;
        bool aux=true;

        while (k < col && aux ){
            if (v[k] == 1) {
                if(m.i[j][k] != w[k])
                    aux=false;
            }
            k++;
        }

        if(aux) r++;
        j++;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This function receives a matrix (defined below), a vector with ones and zeros (to learn which columns to search, a vector with the values we want to search in those columns and also the number of columns (equal to the length of the vectors and matrix). When it strikes the second "if" it gives me Segmentation Fault (I cannot understand what it is), and I can see that it is not correct to define it that way, but I have tried and tried and I can't seem to find a way to access the values in the vector. Here follows my struct matrix:

```
typedef int *ind; 

struct matrix { 
    ind *i;
    int length;
};
typedef struct matrix matrix;
```

In this structure my matrix has a pointer and the length (number of lines); the pointer goes to a vector of pointers (one pointer for each line) and each one of those pointers go to a vector that is, in fact, my line of the matrix. Here go my functions to add and create an empty matrix:

```
matrix emptyS(int n, int col) {
matrix m;
int d=0;
m.length=0;
m.i=(ind*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
int x;
    for (x=0; x < n; x++)
           {
               *m.i = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
           }
while (d<n){
    m.i[d]=NULL;
    d++;
}
return m;
} /*Updated*/

matrix add(matrix m,int v[]){
    m.i[m.length+1]=v;
    m.length++;
    return m;
}
```

I know this is a very specific question but I have been going crazy changing my functions and cannot seem to be successful.

Comment: Could you add a debug print line exactly before the crashing `if` and print the relevant values (`m`, `w`, `m.i`, `j`, `k`)? Or look them up in a debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of `i` is this:

```
 ind *i;
```

You have the following definition of `ind`:

```
typedef int* ind;
```

This means that your definition of `i` really is this:

```
int ** i;
```

Which is a pointer to a pointer, this means you have to allocated your memory incorrectly.

```
m.i=(ind*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

This allocation is only for a `int*`, but what about the second pointer?  You've never allocated any memory for it!

Allocate the rows of the matrix, something like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < nofrows; x++)
   { 
       *m.i = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); 
   }
```

**EDIT**

Your code after you do your allocation for your matrix, sets your pointers in the matrix to `NULL`, essentially leaving all the memory you just allocated *dangling*, with *nothing pointing to it*!!

```
while (d<n){
    m.i[d]=NULL; <--- LEAVES YOUR MEMORY JUST ALLOCATED FOR ROW d DANGLING.
    d++;
}
```

You should not set it to `NULL`, but instead you should write stuff in your matrix you just allocated memory for.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but apparently the `add` function below that seems to be adding rows somehow.

Comment: @Tudor, but I don't see any memory being allocated for the rows, so how could you ever write anything to the rows?  Setting them to `NULL` does not allocate memory!

Comment: I know, that's what I was saying in my answer. But below he has an `add` function which seems to me might be used to pass an allocated row which is then copied to the matrix. But we don't know what he's really doing.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! @Tony The Lion I see what you are saying but I think you're not going towards my problem: I want to create a matrix, represented by a value (the length in number of rows) and a pointer to a vector of pointers (i think it is what I'm doing in my "EmptyS" function). Then I want each of these pointers to point to my rows, meaning position 0 of the vector of pointers points to the first row, position 1 to the second and so on. If I try to allocate memory for my vectors (the rows) won't they be pointers? Because Eclipse tells me I have to cast the memory in a pointer

Comment: @TonyTheLion didn't work, now my EmptyS function looks like this:
    matrix emptyS(int n, int col) {
 matrix m;
 int d=0;
 m.length=0;
 m.i=(ind*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
 int x;
  for (x=0; x < n; x++)
      {
          *m.i = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*col);
      }
 while (d<n){
  m.i[d]=NULL;
  d++;
 }
    return m;
    }

Was this what you were talking about? Thanks!

Comment: @PedroLourenço please post an update in your question, code in comments is not very readable

Comment: Sorry, question updated (thought you could add code to comments, newbie here!)

Comment: @TonyTheLion I see what you're saying and that is what I thought, but the stuff I want to write comes later, in the add function, and I want to have memory allocated for the vector of pointers and later add vectors that are pointed by those pointers, should I pass the allocation of memory to the add function and allocate memory every time a vector is added?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line

```
m.i=(ind*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

by

```
m.i=(ind*) malloc(sizeof(ind)*n);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't work, I also think that my way of accessing the vector in the matrix is wrong, but i'm not sure if the problem is just there :/

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum{false,true}  bool;

typedef struct matrix_ {
    int **rows;
    unsigned size ;
    unsigned used ;
} matrix;

unsigned count (matrix m, int v[], int w[], unsigned ncol) {
    unsigned cnt=0;
    unsigned j=0;

    for (j=0; j < m.used; j++) {
        unsigned k;
        bool aux=true;

        for (k=0;k < ncol && aux; k++ ){
            if (v[k] == 1  && m.rows[j][k] != w[k]) {
                    aux=false;
            }
        }

        if(aux) cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
#define barf(s) do { \
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s); \
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE); \
    } while(0)

matrix emptyS(unsigned siz) {
    matrix m;
    unsigned d;

    m.used=0;
    m.size = siz;
    m.rows = malloc(siz * sizeof *m.rows );

    for (d=0; d<siz; d++){
        m.rows[d]=NULL;
    }
    return m;
}

matrix add(matrix m,int v[]){
    if (m.used >= m.size) barf("Danger, Bill Robinson!" );
    m.rows[m.used++]=v;
    return m;
}
int main(void)
{
int a[] = { 0,1,0};
int b[] = { 0,1,1};
int c[] = { 0,0,0};
int v[] = { 1,0,1};
int w[] = { 0,1,0};
matrix mymatrix;
unsigned zcount;

mymatrix = emptyS(3);
mymatrix = add( mymatrix, a);
mymatrix = add( mymatrix, b);
mymatrix = add( mymatrix, c);

zcount = count(mymatrix, v, w, 3);

printf("Count = %u\n", zcount);

return 0;
}
```

A few 'stylistic' hints:

- for-loops are less error-prone than while() loops, and save two lines.
- for counts and indices, unsigned types are less error-prone. (there is only one corner case)
- Don't hide pointers inside typedefs; it will confuse yourself and others.
- Don't cast malloc()s return value; it is not needed and may suppress error messages.
- `ptr = malloc (n * sizeof *ptr)` is more stable WRT typo's and future edits.
- if you allocate a varable sized object (such as your matrix) store the size (number of elements) **inside** that object. An object should be "self-contained".

Comment: Thank you @wildplasser for your help, but I can't use this structure. This is a project for a subject in my course and we have to follow the implementation as our teacher says so, so avoiding "for" loops, "do" and always casting mallocs (I even thought you couldn't make them work without a cast!) But thanks anyway! :)

Comment: If you think that my version is more readable than yours (or even better), you could tell your teacher he is an idiot. BTW: I fixed the off-by-one in your `m.i[m.length+1]=v;` line.

Comment: yours works and reads perfectly, it's just that I cannot use it, but I will try to adapt it to my version! thank you!